# Запуск 64-разрядного приложения в 32-разрядном окружении

Tags: linux, виртуализация, x86-64

Суть вопроса:
Имеем 32-разрядное окружение Ubuntu, установленное на 64-разрядное железо.
Необходимо запустить приложение х64 в окружении х32.
Виртуализация с помощью гостевой х64 машины не подходит.

Comment: поставьте мультиарч и запустите 64битное окружение.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку в нужном направлении. Возможно ли объяснить путь решения задачи подробнее?

Comment: это почти тоже самое что переставить убунту, ядро тамзапускать другое итд.

Comment: Если библиотеки умеют трамплины, то всё просто, если же нет, всё гораздо сложнее (ядро, кстати, скорее всего должно быть 64 бит).

Comment: ядро  должно быть 64 бит)

Comment: Да, верно. Я уже взгруснул и установил х64, потому что нет решения моей проблеме и это печально.